# Drools, RuleTable and @Watch annotation

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

I have now run out of ideas on how to get a RuleTable in Excel to define the @Watch annotation.

All the Drools documentation shows you how to define the @Watch with individual files, but no mention on how to add this to RuleTables.

My RuleTable is generating 100% at the moment and works fine for a primitive test case, but I need to have the @Watch on a more complex rule.
When I use the test compiler, I can edit the .drl files by hand and upload them to the engine. My rules are firing correctly then.
Some help on how to define this in Excel will be greatly appreciated.

This is the current Excel RuleTable I have defined:
[image]

This is the target .drl I'm aiming for(I have left out the other two rules generated):

```
rule "TestWatch One"
  no-loop
    when
        $payCommResponseDTO: PaymentCommissionResponseDTO(commissionStructure == CommissionStructure.ADJUSTED) @Watch(commissionStructure)
    then
        System.out.println("watch one");
end
```